# SDL2: How to deal with transparency?

Tags: sdl-2, alphablending

I'm experimenting SDL2 and I encounter a case I cannot manage correctly when I draw on an intermediate transparent texture.

The images I'm attempting to blend:

1. [img_w_A_channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWGmT.png)
2. Some solid black color with an alpha of: `255`, `128`, or `0`
3. [window bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2So6n.png) which is optional.

So if I represent this as layers it's as follow

```
img_w_A_channel    img_w_A_channel    img_w_A_channel    img_w_A_channel
                    solid_texture    half_transparent   transparent_texture
   window               window            window            window
```

- On the left, I render the image directly on the window.
- `solid_texture` means a black colored intermediate texture with `alpha=255` where I draw the image in then I draw the texture on the window.
- `half_transparent` means a black colored intermediate texture with `alpha=128` where I draw the image in then I draw the texture on the window.
- `transparent_texture`means a black colored intermediate texture with `alpha=0` where I draw the image in then I draw the texture on the window.

So think about the intermediate texture as a container I want to draw in. So as the window can have a background texture like here, `SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE` is not an option for the intermediate texture.

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see the first and second image (drawn on a solid intermediate texture are identical.
The third and fourth image (drawn on semi-transparent and transparent intermediate texture) are not identical.

The problem is with the image on the right. I want the result to match the image on the left. i.e. being able to draw in a transparent container and get the same result as drawing directly on the window.

My full test code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
SDL_Texture *background = NULL;
SDL_Texture *image = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

SDL_Rect dst = {20, 20, 100, 100};

#define SOLID 255
#define HALF_TRANSPARENT 128
#define TRANSPARENT 0

SDL_Texture * renderImageInATexture(SDL_Texture *image, Uint8 transparency) {

    // Create an intermediate texture
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 200, 200);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);

    // Paint it
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, (Uint8) 0, (Uint8) 0, (Uint8) 0,(Uint8) transparency);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    // Render the image in intermediate texture
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, image, NULL, &dst );

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
    return texture;
}

int main(char *argc, char **argv) {

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

     window = SDL_CreateWindow("Win", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                           800, 200, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // So we can save into pngs to check the value
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);


    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);

    // Fill the window with a texture for fun (doesn't change anything on the problem) can be removed ....
    surface = IMG_Load( "./carbone.png" );
    background = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface );
    SDL_FreeSurface( surface );
    // draw background in main display
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, background, NULL, NULL );
    // .... until here

    surface = IMG_Load( "./image.png" );
    image = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface );
    SDL_FreeSurface( surface );
    // draw imagein main display
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, image, NULL, &dst );

    SDL_Texture *texture = renderImageInATexture(image, SOLID);
    // render intermediate texture in main display
    SDL_Rect dstTexture = {200, 0, 200, 200};
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, texture, NULL, &dstTexture );

    SDL_Texture *texture2 = renderImageInATexture(image, HALF_TRANSPARENT);
    // render intermediate texture2 in main display
    SDL_Rect dstTexture2 = {400, 0, 200, 200};
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, texture2, NULL, &dstTexture2 );

    SDL_Texture *texture3 = renderImageInATexture(image, TRANSPARENT);
    // render intermediate texture3 in main display
    SDL_Rect dstTexture3 = {600, 0, 200, 200};
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, texture3, NULL, &dstTexture3 );


    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(10000);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(image);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(bakcground); // only if you use a background
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

}
```

And to build it:

```
cc main.c -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

Built with SDL 2.0.8 but it doesn't matter.

Any idea to fix this problem?

** EDIT **

So I modified my `renderImageInATexture()` function according to @aram's answer replacing:

```
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
```

by:

```
    SDL_BlendMode mode = SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode(1, 1, 
                                                    SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD,
                                                    1, 1, 
                                                    SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, mode);
```

I also changed my initialization directly in my previous code above to be able to save my screen as proposed by @aram. But I had to use a `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` to prevent a `not supported operation`on `SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode()` call. 
Anyway, I get a `Surface doesn't have a colorkey` message. Is it a problem?

But it seems it's still that `SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode()` not the solution.
First I though that background image was not important because from my tests, I was getting the same result with or without it.
Unfortunately, if @aram's answer gives me the same result as when I render my image in a solid intermediate texture:
[image]

Comment: is there a specific reason for using a render target? you should be able to do this without them, but if you do want to use them you will need a custom blend mode.

Comment: since your new render target is completely transparent you need to use `SDL_BLENDFACTOR_SRC_ALPHA` with `SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE` to take the alpha of what you are rendering.

Comment: also custom blend modes cannot be used with `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE`

Comment: @BradAllred I use SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED. I wrote a test program which shows the result of the more 32000 possible combinations provided by `SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode`, including the ones you propose of course  and none of them allow to get the expected result!  It never takes the intermediate texture transparency set by `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, transparency);` this one is always complety opaque or completely transparent.

Comment: @brad What is strange is that I was at least expecting to the same result as `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);` but no !?!  So I suppose I don't use it correctly and it's not only a problem with the given parameters.

Comment: @BradAllred and As you can see on the image, my render target, if you talk about the intermediate texture I render the white circle in is opaque in the 2nd square, semi-transparent in the 3rd square and transparent in the 4th square.

Comment: I think your question could be improved by providing a clear example of each of your layers and the _expected_ result you are going for rather then the result you get. Its also still unclear why you want to use a render target.

Comment: @BradAllred I think that the first grey rectangle at the 4th line clearly explain what I want to do. I want to render a semi transparent image in a semi transparent texture so I need to call `setRenderTarget( this_texture)` to do that. Then I want to render `this_texture` in the main window So I need `setRenderTarget( NULL)` to do that. The source code is also fully functionnal to experiment what I want to do, I really don't see how I can be clearer than that. Maybe you would have done very differently to get the expected result but I don't see how.

Comment: you can be more clear by providing a _visual_ (not text) example of the expected behavior. there are a lot of possibilities of blending 3 different images, each of which can have their own blend mode. I don't think you understand my question about render targets; nothing in your example demonstrates why you are using one instead of just rendering everything directly to the screen. Good luck.

Comment: @BradAllred The expected behavior is clearly shown by the 1st image where I specify that the 4th square should be the same as the 1st one. And I give the C source file I used to get this result. My question is simple: Do I correctly use the SDL2 available functions. If yes, why do I get this result? Is it because of a possible bug or is it impossible to get the expected result with SDL2? If no, how to modify my code to be able to draw on an intermediate texture without quality loss.

Comment: sorry, i didn't see that you had links to the actual source images before. I was basically asking for you to add them as a visual example to help people more clearly see what you want to do. Images are always better than text no matter how clearly you think you communicate. This should be possible with SDL blending. I can see if I can get you an answer after work if you can answer my question about weather the render target is actually a requirement or simply an artifact of your attempts to blend things.

Comment: Also you need to list what backends you are targeting because custom blend modes dont work for all and many dont support certain customizations. See the remarks section of the docs: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode

Comment: I've added an edit I think will be helpful for people like myself if you wish to review it.

Comment: @BradAllred I'm currently testing this a PC running Ubuntu18 with SDL2.0.8.